# DataFrame loop, use value from previous row as new value and fill the DataFrame. check the code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, filtering

Can not figure out how to create function which could take sum of previous row and use it as new value for next row and repeat it till end of dataframe.

Example: (here we see 2 values and its profit from A to B in %)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A":[4,5,2,2], "B":[5,3,3,4]})
df['Profit_%'] = (df["B"] - df["A"]) / df["A"] * 100
print(df)
```

**Function**:

```
new_col = 'c'

def apply_func_decorator(func):
    prev_row = {}
    def wrapper(curr_row, **kwargs):
        val = func(curr_row, prev_row)
        prev_row.update(curr_row)
        prev_row[new_col] = val
        return val
    return wrapper
@apply_func_decorator
def running_total(curr_row, prev_row):
    return curr_row['Profit_%'] * prev_row.get(new_col, 0) /100 + 125
```

Output:

```
df[new_col] = df.apply(running_total, axis=1)
print(df)
```

So the question would be how to apply the function starting from 2nd row and tell Python that the initial amount to invest is 100$?

So in real life it should be:
We invest 100$ and from first line we get + 25% = 125$
From second line we loose 40% and we loose them from 125$ > and now we have just 75$
From third line we gain 50% and it will be: 112.5$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are just compounding returns, you could simply use a cumulative product:

```
df["C"] = 100*(df["B"]/df["A"]).cumprod()

>>> df
   A  B      C
0  4  5  125.0
1  5  3   75.0
2  2  3  112.5
3  2  4  225.0
```